# javascript vue get value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I want to run through this JSON file and output the values under "states". e.g. Bayern - 220318. How can I access these values in a loop to show them in a list or table?

[image]

Comment: You'd want to use the Object.keys() function.

Something like
Let keys = jsonObject.keys().

for(let i=0;i<keys.length;keys++) {
Console.log(jsonObject[keys[i]]);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the country names then you can define a computed property as below...

```
computed: {
 getStates() {
  return this.output.states; // assuming that you have stored the response in a variable called 'output' defined in the data section
 }
}
```

this is  how you call the computed and print it in your template using v-for

```
<div v-for="(stateObject, state) in getStates" v-bind:key="state">
  <div>{{state}}</div> // to print the state name
  <div>{{stateObject.total}}</div> // to print the total value of that object
  <div>{{stateObject.vaccine}}</div> // to print the vaccine value of that object
 
</div>
```

Comment: '<b-card no-body img-src="https://picsum.photos/300/150/?image=41" img-alt="Image" img-top tag="article"
                    class="mb-2" v-for="result in getStates" v-bind:key="result.key">

                    <div style="margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                        <h4>{{ result.states }}</h4>'

I want to print the values with this vue-html. how can i achieve this?

Comment: your answer overlapped with my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I will do so. But how can i print the "total" or "vaccinated"-value behind the "state"? In "index" there is only a counter.?

Comment: I have modified the computed and template block ...check the updated answer

Comment: OK, Thanks, but it doesn't work. Only the key 0,1,2,... is printed.

Comment: Dude it should work..did you modify the computed property?
I guess you failed to update the update the computed property...please check my code carefully and update it in your code

Comment: sorry, I did not update the computed property. Yes, perfect, now it works very fine :) Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Great...please do upvote/accept my answer!! :)

Comment: Yes, I will do it immediately. updated the result above.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me once more with filtering these data from getStates(). ? I have a code snippet, where can i put this?

Comment: Create it as a seperate question and share the link ...in that way both of us will be benifitted :)

Comment: sorry, too late, have updated the answer :(

Comment: Please dont update the answer...its confusing

Comment: Please add the code block in your question or create this as a seperate question

Comment: OK, I will do so

Comment: If you creating a new question pls share the link here : )

Comment: new question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827954/vue-filtering-values-from-json-with-computed-function

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate the object by keys.

```
Object.keys(output.states).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, output.states[key].vaccinated);
});
```

Comment: THX, yes in this way I can loop through, but I want to have the name of the country e.g. Bayern, Berlin, Brandenburg etc.

Comment: `key` is the country name in your case.

Comment: and how can I use these values to output in vue with v-for? Do I need to save them in an array beforehand?

Comment: yes, you can use computed and object.keys for return keys as value

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

You can read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: THX, but how can I use it in vue to print the values with v-for?

Comment: Do you want to print it one by one?

Comment: You could store it in a data attribute (like in an array, instead of console log just push it in to one) and then v-for on that array :)