# vue filtering values from JSON with computed-function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I filter my array of JSON-data:

This is my markup:

```
  <div v-if="vacciCounter">
        <b-card no-body class="mb-2" v-for="(stateObject, state) in filteredList" v-bind:key="state">

            <div style="margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                <h5>{{ state }}</h5>
```

This is my function:

```
  computed: {
        filteredList() {
            if (this.vacciResults.length > 0) {  
                return this.vacciResults.filter(entry => {
                    return entry.state.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchstring.toLowerCase())

                });
            } 
        },
      
        getStates() {
         return this.vacciResults; // assuming that you have stored the response in a variable called 'output' defined in the data section
           }
```

This is my API function to get the JSON data: vacciResults is fetching the states.

```
fetch(vacciURL, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {

        }

        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {

            this.status = '';
            this.searchBtnDisabled = false;
            

            this.vacciCounter = res.vaccinated;
            this.vacciResults = res.states;
```

[image: result of console log vacciResults]

Comment: vacciResults ...is that your response object?

Comment: yes, this is the response object:

 this.vacciResults = res.states;

Comment: add that code as well in your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was

this.vacciResults is an object and you are tried array operations on it in your computed property

below is modified computed property

```
     computed: {
            filteredList() {
    //********* changes added below ***********
                if (this.searchString !== '' && Object.keys(this.vacciResults).length > 0) { 
                      let filterObject = {};           
                      Object.keys(this.vacciResults).forEach(state => {
                          if(state === this.searchString.toLowerCase()) filterObject[state] = this.vacciResults[state];
                      });
                  return filterObject;
                 }
             return this.vacciResults;              
            },
          
            getStates() {
             return this.vacciResults; // assuming that you have stored the res.states in a variable called 'vacciResults' defined in the data section
             }  
      }
```

Comment: wow, that's great! I will try it at once. THX

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. The list is not displayed :(

Comment: try printing console logs of this.vacciResults, this.searchString inside your computed property

Comment: OK, have tried. No results are shown in the list.

Comment: then to get more understanding pls share the entire code of the file in the question

Comment: Share the full code please including both template and script section

Comment: how is the space on github called where I can put my sources? It is only 1 html and 1 js file.

Comment: not necessary, jus copy the content of your files and paste it in the question as two seperate headings

Comment: code is there: https://gist.github.com/xpediteur/47ff27c3361d9b3b74e67086aa98cbf4

Comment: you should have public access

Comment: Atleast is the list displaying when the search field is empty?

Comment: no, search field is empty at the beginning and there are no data shown. Searching not possible too.

Comment: try printing console.logs inside the computed property and check if anything is undefined

Comment: we should use  state.includes(this.searchString) ... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227639/discussion-between-amaarrockz-and-ralf-borde).